# Android setText causes crash

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to build a small simple program with an image and a textview under it. Like a countdown. I've been trying to runt this program, and everything works except when I get to setText, the program crashes. What could be the problem? I have done a lot of searching and changing, but still get the same problem.

```
package com.ob.IsIt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Isit1337 extends Activity {

ImageView image;
TextView t;
String until;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    until = "fnkar inte";
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.layout.main);
    run();





}
private void run()
{

    if(IsIt.check())
    {

        image.setEnabled(false);

    }

    until = IsIt.timeLeft();

    t.setText("test");


    }
}
```

The IsIt works, the IsIt.check returns a boolean and the IsIt.timeLeft returns a String. 
The xml code looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="bottom|center|center_vertical|top"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="277dp"
    android:layout_height="441dp"
    android:src="@drawable/blackno" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.46"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `t=(TextView)findViewById(R.layout.main);` ? I think the id should be 'R.id.t'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're getting a NullPointerException. (When asking this kind of question, it's better to also paste the relevant LogCat output.) Change this line:

```
t=(TextView)findViewById(R.layout.main);
```

to this:

```
t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write:

```
t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
```

to find the ID for the `TextView`.

Answer (score 2):

ClassCastError because R.id.main is your layout.

It should be:

```
t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
```

Comment: You mean R.layout.main is your layout. That won't cause a ClassCastError because R.layout.main is just an int value.

Answer (score 2):

change it to this

```
t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this for text view:

```
t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView(any widget) should be referered as,
TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);

Layout(xml layout file)only should be refered as,
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main,
            null);
```